# Angular 2/4, bootstrap modals not working with ngFor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm making a web-site on Angular which is already built with bootstrap modals. The problem is that the link that loads the modal doesn't work when the target is loaded dynamically.

How the link should be:

```
<a *ngFor="let item of getData.type_one" class="element type-one" 
[hidden]="isOneHidden" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#preview{{item.id}}">
    ...
</a>
```

How the modal div looks like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of getData.type_one" id="preview{{item.id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    ...
</div>
```

However if I change the link data-target to `data-target="#preview0"` it shows the modal to that preview, it works perfectly even though it's the same string.
Is there any way I can fix it or bypass the problem?

Comment: But why do you have a `jquery` tag? Are you mixing Angular and jQuery together? Unless I'm mistaken, isn't Bootstrap specifically designed for jQuery?

Comment: I added it since bootstrap's JS requires jQuery. The site used to be static so it would require quite a bit of modification in order to replace it and it hasn't shown problems anywhere else thus far.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. jQuery and Angular are absolutely not intended to work together. Singe Angular generates the DOM, the elements created with `*ngFor` do not always exist. They exist only after Angular generates them. And jQuery has no idea what Angular does, therefore it may try binding the events (click etc.) on non-yet-existing elements.

Comment: I know, I tried to keep it in order to save time. However it works without the {{item.id}} so I figured it is possible to solve the problem without re-wrtiting half the project.

Comment: I guess it works with `id="item"` because it's a hard-coded string. But using a dynamic ID such as `id="preview{{item.id}}"` is a problem because your data is asynchronous. So you're asynchronously generating elements for Bootstrap, which expects these elements to be present from the start (because it has no idea of Angular's presence). Sounds pretty complicated to solve, if possible at all. I would instead use a bootstrap-like framework adapted to Angular, such as PrimeNG.

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/
Try using `ngx-bootstrap` This module with `bootstrap` and work with `angular`